# What is clojure.core equivalent of lodash _.pluck

Tags: javascript, clojure, lodash

Lodash [_.pluck](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) does this

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 }
];

_.pluck(users, 'user');
// → ['barney', 'fred']
```

Good thing about it is it can also go deep like this:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': {name: 'barney'}, 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': {name: 'fred'},   'age': 40 }
];

_.pluck(users, 'user.name');
// ["barney", "fred"]
```

Is there equivalent in Clojure core of this? I mean, I can easily create one line somewhat like this

```
(defn pluck
  [collection path]
  (map #(get-in % path) collection))
```

And use it like this:

```
(def my-coll [{:a {:z 1}} {:a {:z 2}}])
(pluck my-coll [:a :z])
=> (1 2)
```

I was just wondering if there's such thing already included in Clojure and I overlooked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are simple tricks:

```
(def my-coll [{:a {:z 1}} {:a {:z 2}}])

(map :a my-coll)
 => ({:z 1} {:z 2})

(map (comp :z :a) my-coll)
 => (1 2)
```

Works because keyword behaves like a function as well.

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in function for this. You can refer to [clojure.core API reference](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html) and [the cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet) to look up what's available.

I would say Clojure's syntax is light enough that it feels sufficient to use a combination of `map` and an accessor utility like `get-in`.

This also demonstrates a well-adopted principle in Clojure community: provide mostly simple defaults and let the users compose them as they need. Some people would probably argue that `pluck` conflates iteration and querying.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is something like:

```
(map #(:user %) users)
```

It will return list `'(36 40)`

Answer (score 0):

`lodash` deprecated `_.pluck` function in favor of `_.map`. Thus:

```
_.pluck(users, 'user')
```

is now

```
_.map(users, 'user')
```

I like the `lodash/fp` flavor, wich put the iteratees in front of the collection

```
_.map('user', users)
```

You also get autocurry for free

```
_.map('user')(users)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function in lodash is now called [pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) and I believe its closest equivalent in Clojure is [select-keys](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/select-keys).